# Doing complex concatenation without SET in Twig

Tags: twig

This code gives error in twig.

```
{{ url( '/?page=signin'
  {% if sidebar %} ~ '&amp;sidebar=' ~ {{ sidebar }}{% endif %}
  {% if post %} ~ '&amp;post=' ~ {{ post }}{% endif %}
  {% if next or page %} ~ '&amp;next=' ~ {{ next ?: page }} {% endif %} ) }}
```

What would be the better way to do this type of concatenation?

Comment: Either create the string in your controller of extend `Twig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work, but it require that each var (sidebar, post…) to be defined. It should contain value, or be `false` (or `null`). Ampersands are escaped automatically. If you'll use `&amp;sidebar` it will be double-escaped (`&amp;amp;`).

```
{{ '/?page=signin' ~ (sidebar ? '&sidebar=' ~ sidebar) ~ (post ? '&post=' ~ post)  }}
```

Comment: You could solve the *is required* part with the `default` filter though : `{{ '/?page=signin' ~ (sidebar|default(null) ? '&sidebar=' ~ sidebar) ~ (post|default(null) ? '&post=' ~ post)  }}`. But i don't feel this is very reuseable